# Removing parts invalid data from panda dataframe (Python)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a file with data that I'm trying to put into graphs and such. In some parts of the data, there are `-` characters that represent not collected data. I know `data.dropna()` would normally do the job, but the missing data is represented by `-` instead.

Comment: Couple options.  Assuming you're using read_csv(), you could use the na_values arg.   Or you do something like this `df.replace('-', np.nan).dropna()`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose I have a csv file `test.csv` that looks like

```
col1,col2,col3
1,-,2
-,3,4
```

I can tell `pd.read_csv` to handle `'-'` like `nan` when it's read in

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', na_values=['-'])

df

   col1  col2  col3
0   1.0   NaN     2
1   NaN   3.0     4
```

From there, you can `dropna` as normal